# How to create a new session after deleting the previous one?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to setup a session after complete destroy sessions, here is my code:

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 0,$params["path"], $params["domain"],$params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
}
session_destroy();
$_SESSION['message-success-l']='Email changed, now you can login!';
header ('location: https://example.com/login');
die();
```

//php login

```
session_start();
echo "$_SESSION['message-success-l']";
```

So after the change of the email all sessions will destroy and user can now re-login, but after the completly session destroy I want setup a session that say that the changes went succesfully.

But when I go to the login page I see no session message why?

Comment: I really don't get your code... u set the session and destroy and open a session and redirect....seems to me like a xy-problem

Comment: You should not declare $_SESSION like you did. It is natively accessible as soon as you initialize the session system with `session_start()`. Also, you need to initialize the session system on every page that might need to access `$_SESSION`.

Comment: `$_SESSION = array();` thats kinda wierd ...

Comment: @Cyphall I have did it but seems not work

Answer (score 0):

I would never use a session for just a message... anyway this is the working code

**session-destroy.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
// YOUR CODE
session_destroy();
header("Location: email-changed.php");
?>
```

**email-changed.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = "Email changed, now you can login!";
header("Location: home.php");
?>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

errors: 
echo "$_SESSION['message-success-l']"; -> echo $_SESSION['message-success-l']; // without quote ,
 $_SESSION = array(); // why use an array.
(honestly i don't know) you can't create a new session after session_destroy();
sorry for my eng, i hope this is useful bye

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're setting a $_SESSION variables when it just got destroyed, meaning there is no session.

I think you're mixing something up. Let's think of the workflow

You get to a page, and you want `session_start();` at it.

What you want to do is: Whenever the email is changed or logout (assuming theres a logout function since aparently emails can be changed), you'll want `session_destroy();` at the end of this operation.

That's it. Whenever `session_destroy();` hits, it's gone. Whenever it starts, it enables it

What you do in the middle, that's up to you, if you want to create session variables and place content on them. To maintain a session from page to page, just maintain `session_start();` at every desired page.

Repeat: Once it's destroyed, it's destroyed. What you're doing in your code is starting a session (or maintaining it from the previous page/operation), then (no idea why you've got $_SESSION there, it's worthless) you validate it and finally, you destroy it.

Why are you alocating a message to your `$_SESSION` if you've just destroyed it? There is no session at this point. YOU COULD write `session_start()` afterwards but then again, why would you start->destroy->start again when, quite possibly, when you redirect to login there is a start?